# What is the best indices for a query with variable where clause

Tags: database, oracle, indexing

I have a query which always filter results with these columns in the query where clause (creation_date, expiry_date) combined with none,any or all of these columns (organization_id, user_id, status, transaction_id). What is the best index or indices I could use for such query?

Answer (score 0):

If the columns creation_date, expiry_date are sparse (number of unique creation_date or expiry_date or both are approximately equal to number of records) then you can create either index on creation_date or expiry_date or both.

I will recommend index on creation_date and expiry_date. As combination will be sparser than individual columns.

Comment: What about the other columns

Comment: You need to understand the average number of records it will return for each and every combination. If you keep on adding indexes your DML will become slow. As I have mentioned earlier if number of unique values of creation and expiry date is almost equal to total number of records in the table, there is no need of including other columns in the index or create new ones for others.